# Flask not reading Secret_key when FLASK_ENV = 'production'

Tags: flask

I have a simple Flask app with Config file having Config, Prod and Debug Classes. I have a .env in project root folder, containing the secrets. When I config using Debug it reads the secret key. But when I set it to use Prod it complains:

> RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.

I am not using Sessions. Here is the code for Config.py:

```
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))


class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = environ.get('DB_URI')

class ProdConfig(Config):
    FLASK_ENV = 'production'
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False

class DevConfig(Config):
    FLASK_ENV = 'development'
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
```

Here goes **init**.py

```
def create_app(config_class=ProdConfig):
    flask_app = Flask(__name__)
    flask_app.config.from_object(config_class)
```

Here is run.py which I use to run the project:

```
from server import create_app
from server.config import DevConfig

app = create_app()
# app = create_app(DevConfig)
csrf.init_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When using DevConfig it works fine but not with ProdConfig. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))


class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = environ.get('DB_URI')

class ProdConfig(Config):
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY_FOR_PROD')
    FLASK_ENV = 'production'
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False

class DevConfig(Config):
    FLASK_ENV = 'development'
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
```

app.py

```
def create_app():
    flask_app = Flask(__name__)
    flask_app.config.from_object(config.ProdConfig)
```